# Size against best Bid or best Ask in Bloomberg Excel API

Tags: bloomberg

I need best ask and best bid at interval of five minutes along with the corresponding size. Using Intraday Bars in Excel, I am able to obtain the best ask and best bid but not able to able the corresponding size. The size that it shows is the summation of all sizes at a particular price, which is not the requirement. Using intraday ticks in Excel, I can see the size against the bid. But finding the best bid and then noting the corresponding size is very cumbersome process which will take years. Can you please help in obtaining size against the best bid. Also, it would be great if you could give me some template to obtain the best bid and the corresponding size or let me know the steps.

Answer (score 0):

For the Refresh, you could do something like: 
http://excelexperts.com/VBA-Tips-Run-Code-Every-Hour-Minute-or-Second

Bloomberg has fields for BID, ASK, and BID_SIZE -- so you should just be able to use the built in fields. Field "RQ014 - Bid Size (BID_SIZE)" says it uses the "best bid" level.

Comment: Dear, (BID_SIZE) is for the real data. the study requires size (Bid or Ask) for for the historical data.